# xpath. Select element if brother value

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

```xml
<tr>
    <td>AAA</td>
    <td>
        <a class="btn" role="button"> </a>
    <td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>bbb</td>
    <td>
        <a class="btn" role="button"> </a>
    <td>
</tr>
```

How to select `a` if `tr` contains `<td>AAA</td>`. Perfect if I can do it with XPath. But maybe another way in WebDriver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `Xpath`.

`//td[text() = 'AAA']/following-sibling::td/a`

This will get find a `td` which has the text `AAA`. Then it will select the following `td` sibling and get the `a` from this `td`.